How to control the persistence order of Spring Data Repository Populator?
I'm populating some initial data for a project and my configuration class:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.io.*;
import org.springframework.data.repository.init.*;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryDataInitializer {

    protected Resource[] getResources() {
        return new Resource[]{
                new ClassPathResource("initial-data/permission.json"),
                new ClassPathResource("initial-data/permission-set.json"),
                new ClassPathResource("initial-data/user.json"),
                new ClassPathResource("initial-data/user-group.json"),
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean securityRepositoryPopulator() {
        var factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(getResources());
        factory.setMapper(new ObjectMapper()
                .findAndRegisterModules()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        );
        return factory;
    }

}

My json data:
// permission.json
[{
    "_class": "org.ximinghui.study.permission.Permission",
    "name": "CREATE_ACCOUNT",
    "description": "Ability to create an account"
}, {
    "_class": "org.ximinghui.study.permission.Permission",
    "name": "CREATE_PERMISSION"
}]



// permission-set.json
[{
    "_class": "org.ximinghui.study.permission.PermissionSet",
    "ownerAccount": "123",
    "number": 1,
    "name": "SecurityAdmin",
    "permissions": [{
        "name": "CREATE_ACCOUNT"
    }]
}, {
    "_class": "org.ximinghui.study.permission.PermissionSet",
    "ownerAccount": "123",
    "number": 2,
    "name": "InitializationTest",
    "permissions": ["CREATE_ACCOUNT", "CREATE_PERMISSION"]
}]



// user.json
[{
    "_class": "org.ximinghui.study.user.User",
    "ownerAccount": "123",
    "userId": "8f3e",
    "username": "ximinghui",
    "password": "123456",
    "firstName": "Xi",
    "lastName": "Minghui",
    "sex": "MALE",
    "birthday": "1998-01-01",
    "lastLoginTime": "2024-11-04T23:27:31+00:00",
    "userGroups": [],
    "permissions": ["CREATE_ACCOUNT"],
    "permissionSets": [{
        "ownerAccount": "123",
        "number": 2
    }],
    "isEnabled": true
}]



// user-group.json
[{
    "_class": "org.ximinghui.study.user.UserGroup",
    "ownerAccount": "123",
    "groupNumber": 1,
    "groupName": "Guests",
    "members": [{
        "ownerAccount": "123",
        "userId": "8f3e"
    }],
    "permissions": ["CREATE_ACCOUNT"],
    "permissionSets": [{
        "ownerAccount": "123",
        "number": 2
    }]
}]

When I start the project I get the error:
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.ximinghui.study.user.User
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:368) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:795) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:758) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:676) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:426) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy157.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.init.ResourceReaderRepositoryPopulator.persist(ResourceReaderRepositoryPopulator.java:160) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.init.ResourceReaderRepositoryPopulator.populate(ResourceReaderRepositoryPopulator.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.init.AbstractRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.init.AbstractRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.java:38) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:384) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:984) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.lptcorporation.audit.Main.main(Main.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.ximinghui.study.user.User
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1429) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:487) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2324) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1981) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.ximinghui.study.user.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityIdentifierMapping.getIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(EntityIdentifierMapping.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.EmbeddedForeignKeyDescriptor.getAssociationKeyFromSide(EmbeddedForeignKeyDescriptor.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ManyToManyCollectionPart.decompose(ManyToManyCollectionPart.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.applyInsertRowValues(BasicCollectionPersister.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.mutation.InsertRowsCoordinatorStandard.insertRows(InsertRowsCoordinatorStandard.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.recreate(BasicCollectionPersister.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:632) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:499) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

Setting the cascade attribute of the JPA entity relationship annotation to a CascadeType with cascade updates is not what I need, I designed these entities to not allow cascade persistence.
I tried putting User first in the configuration class, which did not work, and the error I got was the same. And there is an interesting phenomenon: if I comment out the code new ClassPathResource("initial-data/user-group.json") and try to run, the project can complete the data initialization work, and then uncomment and try to run, I get an error.
I think if I can control the RepositoryPopulator to persist in the order of Permission, PermissionSet, User, UserGroup, I can solve this problem or is my thinking in the wrong direction?
Thanks a lot for any information!
